# Chaining Immutable.js methods with deeply nested Maps/Lists

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have an Immutable.js collection that looks like this:

```
{ groups: Immutable.Map({
    {
      id: 1,
      members: Immutable.List
    },{
      id: 2,
      members: Immutable.List
    }
  })
}
```

I'm getting an updated members array and the group id from my server. How can I find the correct group by id and then update the members prop and then return a new `groups` collection?

I have something like this so far that doesn't work.

```
return state.update('groups', groups => {
  for (let group of groups) {
    if (group.id === action.id) {
      group.members = Immutable.fromJS(action.members);
      // not sure what I would do with updated here
      //const updated = group.members.set('members', action.members);
    }
  }

  return groups;
};
```

Also, tried this and it doesn't seem to complete, because the `console.log` never fires.

```
    let update = state.get('groups')
                      .find(group => group.id === action.id)
                      .set('members', action.members)
    console.log(update) // nothing, no error either
```

The following works, but there has to be a better, more elegant way than using `fromJS` and then `toJS`.

```
return state.update('groups', groupsImmutable => {
  const groups = groupsImmutable.toJS();
  for (let group of groups) {
    if (group.id === activeId) {
      group.members = action.members;
      break;
    }
  }

  return Immutable.fromJS(groups);
});
```

thanks!

Comment: Does it work to do `return state.setIn(['groups', action.id, 'members'], action.members)`?

Comment: @JeremyS. That didn't work. I ended up using the last option

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
return state.update('groups', groups => {
    return groups.map(group => {
        if (group.get('id') === action.id) {
            return group.set('members', Immutable.fromJS(action.members))
        } else {
            return group
        }
    })
})
```

You could also use `findIndex` to get the index of the matching group id and then use `setIn` to update the members array:

```
const updateIndex = state.get('groups').findIndex(group => group.get('id') === action.id);
if (updateIndex === -1) { // action.id not found
    return state;
} else {
    return state.setIn(['groups',updateIndex,'members'], Immutable.fromJS(action.members))
}
```

Your examples failed because you were trying to directly modify a child element, that's not how Immutable works.  You need to update the entire state object with the new element.